# Image orientation changed in picasso

Tags: android, json, imageview, orientation, picasso

I'm creating an android application in which I'm using Picasso jar to load the image from JSON, Here some images are displayed in a wrong orientation. Not every image, but only some. Can you please help me overcome this issue:

```
Picasso.with(Sell_Preview_Activity.this)
                .load(Httppost_Links.imagePath
                        + ConstantVariables.sellDetails_stringURL)
                .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
                .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)
                .into(view_imageView, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        if (progressBar != null) {
                            Log.i("image loading success",
                                    "image loading success  ");
                            progressBar1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {

                    }
                });
```

Comment: can you give an example of an image that is correct, and one that is wrong?

Comment: image in db is like http://prntscr.com/8wxrpo, while it appears in my device as follows: http://prntscr.com/8wxsay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Improvising on the answer put forward by Zhli, have you tried the other options available in the same link :

[Image Rotation in Picasso](https://futurestud.io/blog/picasso-image-rotation-and-transformation/)

Answer (score 2):

I didn't come across such issue.
But I suspect that it may due to your ImageView's height and width.
you could call `.resize(100, 100)` or `.fit()`

hope this could help you
https://futurestud.io/blog/picasso-image-resizing-scaling-and-fit/